# Creating a json object from nsmutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have got three nsmutablearray imageNameArray,imageSizeArray,baseArray.

I have to create a json of following type.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "file_size": 48597,
      "file_name": "pisa-en.pdf",
      "file_content": "base64String"
    }
  ]
}
```

since the number of elements within document array might vary, Im trying to create nsdictionary from arrays as follows,

```
for (int i = 0; i< [_imageNameArray count]; i++){
                [dictionary setValue:self.imageNameArray[i] forKey:@"file_name"];
                [dictionary setValue:self.imageSizeArray[i] forKey:@"file_size"];
                [dictionary setValue:self.baseArray[i] forKey:@"file_content"];

            }
```

but it is not creating the json of required type. When Im trying to print it, there exists an equals to symbol between key and value.

Comment: can you post your created json after this

Comment: `NSMutableArray *allDocuments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];for (int i = 0; i < [_imageNameArray count]; i ++){NSMutableDictionary *aDocument = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];[aDocument setObject:self.imageNameArray[i] forKey:@"file_name"];[aDocument setObject:self.imageSizeArray[i] forKey:@"file_size"];[aDocument setObject:self.baseArray[i] forKey:@"file_content"];[allDocuments addObject:aDocument];}NSDictionary *topLevel = @{@"documents":allDocuments};`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to check in console that it is equal symbol or colon. If you want to send data to server then first convert it in data like,

```
NSDictionary *dict ; // your dict or array

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
```

It will convert it in colon (:) instead of `=`.

And if you are using `AFNetworking` then you not need to do this jsonserialization, you can directly pass dictionary or array as parameter in method and afnetworking manage all things.

Hope this will help :)